# Strange SyntaxError in while open

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, syntax-error

Have a pretty strange **syntax error** here. If I am missing something here let me know. The problem is with what is added after the **while open** statement. It is only on this line and I have checked the syntax both in debugging and using [pep8online](http://pep8online.com/checkresult), yet still have this syntax error. The debugger always points at the "**as** infile:" Is this a bug? I don't see any syntax problems. Appreciate the help.

```
def main(argv):
    try:
        while open("b.txt", "r") as infile:
            start = infile.read()
        for line in start:
            r = massextract(line)
            r.go()
    except IOError as e:
        print("Open error: {0}".format(e))
        sys.exit(0)
    except SyntaxError as e:
        print("Syntax error: {0}".format(e))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: That should be `with`, not `while`.

Comment: That does it. Thanks! Overlooked that one.